# Mount NFS Volume in Docker Containers when connected to NordVPN Docker Container

Tags: docker, vpn, nfs

I'm currently trying to figure out how to correctly mount my NFS Share to my Docker Containers: *radarr, sonarr, sabnzbd* and *jdownloader*. The Containers routing all the traffic over the vpn service container "nordvpn".

When I'm trying to open the NFS folders they are just empty. So I guess the mount doesn't work correctly.
I also tried to connect only the sabnzbd service without the nordvpn container to the NFS share. This also didn't worked for me.

My Compose File:

```
version: "3"
services:
  vpn:
    image: bubuntux/nordvpn:3.7.4  # olderversion caused by a connection error 
    container_name: nordvpn
    network_mode: bridge        # Required
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN               # Required
      - SYS_MODULE              # Required for TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun            # Required
    environment:                # Review https://github.com/bubuntux/nordvpn#environment-variables
      - USER=xxx     # Required
      - "PASS=xxx"         # Required
      - CONNECT=Netherlands
      - TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
      - NETWORK=192.168.2.0/24 
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080   # sabnzbd
      - 7878:7878   # radarr
      - 8989:8989   # sonarr
      - 5800:5800   # jdownloader
      

  sabnzbd:
    image: linuxserver/sabnzbd
    container_name: sabnzbd
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    volumes:
    #  - "./config/sabnzbd:/config" # sab config directory
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share/Complete_Down:/complete_downloads" # completed directory for downloads. this contains the category directories
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share/Temp_Down:/temp_downloads" # "temp" directory for downloads
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share:/storage/Share"
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/xxx:/storage/Filme"
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/xxx:/storage/Serien"
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/xxx:/storage/Spiele"
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      PUID: 99 # set to UID of your user
      PGID: 99 # set to GID of your user

  radarr:
    image: linuxserver/radarr
    container_name: radarr
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    volumes:
    #  - "./config/radarr:/config" # config directory for radarr
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share/Complete_Down:/complete_downloads" # completed downloads directory from sab
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/xxx/storage/Filme/HD" # where radarr will copy your movies. add as many of these as you need
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      PUID: 99 # set this to the UID of your user
      PGID: 99 # set this to the GID of your user

  sonarr:
    image: linuxserver/sonarr
    container_name: sonarr
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    volumes:
    #  - "./config/sonarr:/config" # sonarr config dir
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share/Complete_Down:/complete_downloads" # completed downloads directory 
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/xxx:/storage/Serien"
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      PUID: 99 # set this to the UID of your user
      PGID: 99 # set this to the GID of your user


  #initialize jdownloader Docker Image 
  jdownloader-2:
    image: jlesage/jdownloader-2
    container_name: jdownloader
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    volumes:
      - "/docker/appdata/jdownloader-2:/config"
      - "/192.168.2.222/mnt/array1/Share/Complete_Down:/output"
```

I also tried it like this

```
volumes: 
    share: 
     driver: local 
     driver_opts: 
     type: nfs 
     o: addr=192.168.2.222,rw 
     device: ":/mnt/array1/Share"
```

Any ideas ?